# print programs(or path of program files) called by a python program

Tags: python

I am calling a module in my python program that contains a set of python and few C++ programs. 
I would like to know if there is a way to print the list of programs called when I execute my program. The module was not written by me and contains many programs, so I would like to avoid printing path in each program present.

Please can someone let me know if this or something similar is possible.

Thanks

Comment: Quite difficult without any knowledge at all about your python program or the called module...

Comment: any terminal command that can help? I have tried systrace but the output is too detailed and since there are many programs, it does not help.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace sys.stdout with a trash file write object to avoid the statements you don't want.

```
import sys

class TrashFile(object):
    def write(self, arg):
        pass

i_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = TrashFile()

# Stop printing output on screen
print_trash()

sys.stdout = i_stdout

# Start to print
print_statement()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very specific.  I assume that your python module invokes separate programs (i.e. using calls such as os.system(), or the standard module 'subprocess'), and that you want to determine which programs are invoked.

Here is a trivial python program which invokes a subprocess:

```
import os
os.system("echo hello")
```

If you are using linux, you can use the tool 'strace' to track all system calls a program makes (not just python programs).

If your python program is called 'foo.py', then you can run strace like this:

```
strace -f -e trace=process python foo.py 2>output
```

I'll break down what this does:

- -f causes strace to track subprocesses (and their system calls).
- "-e trace=process" tells strace to track only process-related system calls.  This reduces the amount of output from strace.
- strace outputs to the stderr stream - we save this to the file 'output'.

For the above program, the output looks like this:

```
execve("/usr/bin/python", ["python", "foo.py"], [/* 50 vars */]) = 0
clone(Process 1735 attached
child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_PARENT_SETTID|SIGCHLD, parent_tidptr=0xbfe2b2ec) = 1735
[pid  1732] waitpid(1735, Process 1732 suspended
 <unfinished ...>
[pid  1735] execve("/bin/sh", ["sh", "-c", "echo hello"], [/* 50 vars */]) = 0
[pid  1735] exit_group(0)               = ?
Process 1732 resumed
Process 1735 detached
<... waitpid resumed> [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0) = 1735
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) @ 0 (0) ---
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

Search for "exec" to find where subprocesses are invoked.  In this example there are two of them: where python itself was invoked, and where python invoked "/bin/sh".

Hope this helps.